# How to do 2-stage logistic regression in R, using instrumental variable

Tags: r

The question is, given patients' pre-treat features and after-treat features, how to remove the effect of payment, when a doctor choosing the method of treatment?
thats is :

T=b3*X+b4*Z+U2

Y=b1*X+b2*T+U1

Z means payment, the instrumental variable.

Does instrumental variable estimation work? Is this a correct usage of IV?

```
lm_1st=glm(gettreat ~ pre+pay,data = traindata,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
lm_2nd=glm(restatus ~ pre+gettreat,data = traindata,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(lm_2nd)
```

Comment: This seems more like a question about math, rather than one about programming. If so, you might have more luck asking on [stats.se] or [math.se]